# Selecting a particular row when grouping data

Tags: mysql

```
StudentId  QuestionId  Incorrect  Unanswered Flagged  pace  id  SubtopicId
==========================================================================
1          1           1          0          0        2     1   1
1          1           0          0          0        4     2   1
1          2           0          0          0        8     3   1
```

I have this table with the above values in it. I want to select all the the questions attempted by a student for a particular subtopic only once. In case there are multiple entries for a question i want to select the one with the greater id. I couldn't figure out a way to select the question with the greater id.
This is what i am trying.

```
SELECT QuestionId
     , pace
     , id 
  From table 
 where StudentId = 1 
   and SubtopicId = 1 
 Group 
    By QuestionId 
 Order 
    BY id desc;
```

Can anyone please tell me the modifications in my query or suggest a new one?

Comment: `my-sql` is not the same as `sql-server`... please remove the extra tag.

Comment: what is the expected answer for your data?

Comment: SELECT *
    From table t1
    where not exists
    (
      SELECT *
      From table t2
      where t2.StudentId = t1.StudentId and t2.SubtopicId = t1.SubtopicId and
            t2.QuestionId = t1.QuestionId and t2.id > t1.id
    )
    where StudentId = 1 and SubtopicId = 1

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try:

```
SELECT QuestionId, MAX(id) AS MaxId
FROM table
WHERE StudentId = 1
  AND SubtopicId = 1
GROUP BY QuestionId
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: No, Id is what denotes multiple entries for the same question.

Comment: The result that i want should be the second and the third row. But what i get is the first row and the third row

Comment: @AliAhmad, should be good now.